# Zend framework 2 - How to make a language switcher

Tags: php, zend-framework2, translation

I am developing a Zend Framework 2 Application and now I want to implement a language switcher from where guest/registered user can choose the language they want, the thing I can't understand is how is it made in Zend Framework 2 using the storage ( not from urls ), I want to keep the preffered language of guest in the storage once he selects one, and for the registered users I can retrieve the preffered one from cookie/database and reuse it with storage. But where and how should I start/implement this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setup your `Locales` in your `global.config.php`:

```
'locale' => array(
    'default' => 'en_US',
    'available'     => array(
        'de_DE' => 'Deutsch',
        'nl_NL' => 'Dutch',
        'en_US' => 'English',
        'fr_FR' => 'French',
    ),
),
```

So in your `Application\Module.php` you can add a method which sets the default `Zend\Translator\Translator`:

```
class Module {

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $applicaton = $e->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        // Just a call to the translator, nothing special!
        $serviceManager->get('translator');
        $this->initTranslator($e);

        // Etc, more of your bootstrap function.
    }

    protected function initTranslator(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        // Zend\Session\Container
        $session = New Container('language');

        $translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');
        $translator
            ->setLocale($session->language)
            ->setFallbackLocale('en_US');
    }
}
```

So now the default Locale is **en_US** as the session has no Locale available. For changing the locale you need to catch the users input and validate the available locales you support, provided in your `global.config.php`. So in order to change it you might need to add a controller action which catches the input of the user and sets the new locale. Example of the controller action without any form usage!

```
public function changeLocaleAction() 
{
    // New Container will get he Language Session if the SessionManager already knows the language session.
    $session = new Container('language');
    $language = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->language;
    $config = $this->serviceLocator->get('config');
    if (isset($config['locale']['available'][$language]) {
        $session->language = $language;
        $this->serviceLocator->get('translator')->setLocale($session->language);
    }
}
```

The session allows the users to change their locale and remember it until the session ends, so they won't need to change it when they get back after a while. Hope this will help you and can help you to write some code to save it for your registered users on your application.

Comment: Great explanation and solution. It works and now I understand how to use the translator, I was thinking that is more complicated or you just explained it very good to understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: I followed exactly as you explained, but doesn't work. Can you add module.config.php file as well.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri as in which step is not clear to you? The `module.config.php` shouldn't be of any concern. Notice there are some typo's in the code so don't just blindly copy paste it and think it might work for you. Maybe you can add a little more info about what doesn't works for you.

Comment: First of all , I don't have `global.config.php` by default in zend skeleton, so I have created new file. I am bit of lost on this here. I am learner of Zend, not getting the point of changing locale.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri take a look at: [autoload](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/modules.html#informing-the-application-about-our-new-module). In your `application.config.php` you probably have an autoloader setup in which case you can create a file called global.php in the following map `<projectName>/config/autload`. If you don't have those maps, create it. This `global.php` is just an additional array config file where you can register any services or options just for your project/application. That's why I told you to add the locales to the `global.php`

Comment: Yes, I have created this file in the `autoload`. Not sure, why this doesn't work. However I will try your solution in my fresh zend skeleton. Thanks for replying.

Comment: `$request`, how is this called? This is not initiated I think.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri - `$request = $this->getRequest()`

Comment: @Kwido huge thanks to you mate. I owe you a beer. I have posted my answer here for more detail though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006818/whats-the-best-option-to-have-language-switcher-in-my-zf2-system/35128760#35128760

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, my approach will work or not. Please try:

We can have 3 params for `translate` method.

```
$translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
```

The $locale parameter is taken from the locale, set in the translator and that's why we usually not set manually in the code. So, you can use like below :

```
$localeVar = 'de_DE';  OR  $localeVar = 'en_US'; // according to user's selection
echo $this->translate("Translate me", $textDomain, $localeVar);
```

You can have a key value pair - key can be user selected language and value can be any one of the language.

```
array(
    'english' => 'en_US',
    'deutch' => 'de_DE',
    'frecnh' => 'fr_FR',
    // other language
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the one from Kudo was the solution that worked for me and understood.