# how create to language switcher in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How to create language switcher in my application?
I use Zend Framework 2.

index.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Users') ?>
```

module.config.php:

```
'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'pl_PL',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

I have pl_PL.mo and everything works but how add switcher?

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956272/zend-framework-2-how-to-make-a-language-switcher)

Comment: chodzi o to, że tamto nie działa