# php:zf2 multi-currency implementation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am new to zf2. In my current website I need to implement multi-currency selection. What I have done is created  a .global file in the application module and added the below list

```
return array(
    'currency' =>array(
        'default_currency'=>'GBP',
        'currency_list'=> array(
            'GBP'=>'UK(£)',
            'USD'=>'USA($)',
            'EUR'=>'EU Euro(€)',
            'HKD'=>'HK Dollar(HKD)',
            'CHF'=>'Swiss Franc(CHF)',
            'JPY'=>'Japan Yen(¥)',
            'SGD'=>'Sing Dollar(SGD)'
        )
    )
);
```

This is above list will show in my menu bar. What is need is when the user selects the currency the website must set that currency as the default currency for the entire website. 
I do this in the bootstrap function of the Module.php but it does not work correctly.

```
$eventManager->attach('route', function ($event) {
                $sm = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
                $config = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Configuration');
                // locale language
                $localesConfig = $config['locales'];
                $locales = $localesConfig['lang_list'];
                $locale = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('locale');

                $localeCurrencyConfig = $config['currency'];
                $localesCurrency = $localeCurrencyConfig['currency_list'];
                $localeCurrency = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('curr');

                // unsupported lacale provided default to en 
                if (!in_array($locale, array_keys($locales)))
                    $locale = $localesConfig['default_lang'];
                // unsupported currency provided default to GBP
                if (!in_array($localeCurrency, array_keys($localesCurrency)))
                    $localeCurrency = $localeCurrencyConfig['default_currency'];

                // If there is no locale parameter in the route, switch to default locale en 
                if (empty($locale))
                    $locale = $localesConfig['default_lang'];
                if (empty($localeCurrency))
                    $localeCurrency = $localeCurrencyConfig['default_currency'];

                $translator = $sm->get('translator');
                $translator->setLocale($locale);
                $viewHelperManager = $sm->get('ViewHelperManager');
                $viewHelperManager->get("currencyFormat")->setCurrencyCode($localeCurrency); 
}, -10);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in an event? I would just create a new route (and controller) that accepts a currency and a redirect URL.

Comment: how do I use it in the whole website. when currency is needed. do i need to store in a session and use it.

Comment: Yes, I would store the currency in the session.

Comment: This post helped me a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956272/zend-framework-2-how-to-make-a-language-switcher. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// Fetching JSON
$req_url = 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/API_KEY/latest/USD';
$response_json = file_get_contents($req_url);
print_r($response_json);

// Continuing if we got a result
if(false !== $response_json) {

    // Try/catch for json_decode operation
    try {

        // Decoding
        $response = json_decode($response_json);

        // Check for success
        if('success' === $response->result) {

            // YOUR APPLICATION CODE HERE, e.g.
            $base_price = 10; // Your price in USD
            $EUR_price = round(($base_price * $response->conversion_rates->AUD), 2);
            echo"\n\n".$EUR_price;

        }

    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // Handle JSON parse error...
    }

}
```