# ZF 2 Form Validation Translations

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, translation

I use ZF 2.4 and I would like to change form validation messages to German, so I used code compatible with doc - https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html

```php
$translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    './vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/en/Zend_Validate.php', //or Zend_Captcha
    'default',
    'de_DE'
);
\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

Unfortunatelly EN is used still.. For example message "Value is required and can't be empty" is displayed from `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Validator/NotEmpty.php` and isn't translated from `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php`

No errors are there...

Could somebody help me, please? This is very important for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translator is still pointing to the Locale of EN. What you want to do is set the translator Locale based on the user settings or maybe even a route parameter. To do that use the `setLocale($locale)` on your `Translator`.

So you could do this within your `Application\Module.php`:

```
$language = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('language', 'en_US');
$serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');
$translator
    ->setLocale($language)
    ->setFallbackLocale('en_US')
    ->addTranslationFilePattern(
        'phpArray',
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\Resources::getBasePath(),
        \Zend\I18n\Translator\Resources::getPatternForValidator()
    );

AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

It is up to you to where you get the language locale from. If you don't have a route param defined for the language but want to use the user settings for example:

```
$language = 'en_US';
$authService = $auth = $serviceManager->get('zfcuser_auth_service');
if ($authService->hasIdentity()) {
    $language = $authService->getIdentity()->getUserSettings()->getLanguage();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work still.... I used something similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956272/zend-framework-2-how-to-make-a-language-switcher because methods from Your post doesn't exists (Resources::getBasePath(), Resources::getPatternForValidator())

Comment: do You have any idea? I thought that code from my first post should work, because in array "default" was passed.. so I thought that it is set as default locale

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have used the FQCN instead of just plain `Resource`. Will update my answer. BTW: you don't need to create a new instance of the translator. Use the default `Translator` which is included within the `ServiceManager`. If you check out the `Translator` you've created the locale is probaly null as you did not set it and within the class there is no default. And maybe you could create the translator by using: `Translator::factory($options)`

Comment: Unfortunatelly in ZF 2 Resources not exists in \Zend\I18n\Translator\...

Comment: I was looking for method getPatternForValidator on whole project and this method not exists also...

Comment: I used code from my second post and this works now.. it's strange, really strange

Comment: The `Resources` are a sub component of the i18n Translator, which you probaly need to include or you could use its value(s). [Zend i18n Resources](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-i18n-resources/blob/master/src/Resources.php)

Answer (score 0):

Haa, it works when I used below code:

```
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
$serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
    $translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');

    //$locale = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    $locale = 'de_DE';
    //$locale = 'en_US';

    $translator->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($locale));
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        './vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php',
        'default',
        'de_DE'
    );
    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
}
```

I don't understand why it wasn't working before..